# client sent plain HTTP request to HTTPS port while reading client request headers error when connecting to Nginx using java.net.Proxy

Tags: java, nginx, https, proxy

I'm using java.net.Proxy to connect to my server via Nginx proxy. The Nginx proxy is SSL enabled. My server URL is https.

When I try the example code below I'm getting 400 error:

> client sent plain HTTP request to HTTPS port while reading client request headers

This is probably happening since I cannot specify in the code "https" as the proxy ip address so Nginx proxy thinks its an http request, and generates the error.

It works fine when Nginx proxy SSL is disabled or when I connect directly to my server.

Can this be solved programatically, or only by configuring the Nginx proxy to redirect http requests to https ?

```
String url = "https://myserver.com"; 
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4", 444)); 
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection(proxy)); 
con.connect();
```